# What is the fastest--to-install TeX to HTML converter for windows?

Tags: installing, conversion, windows, html

I just came by this http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-mswin.html

And I find it a bit extreme to need 20 steps just to set up a software.

Is there any simpler, more reasonable, alternative?

Comment: One could write the same in 4 steps: 1. install dependencies (ImageMagick, maybe Java) 2. copy tex4ht files 3. Configure tex4ht to your needs 4. Set the Windows PATH variable correctly and update the TeX database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is an easy to install (cross-platform, with windows installer available) markup format to markup format converter that among others supports `latex` as input format and `html` as output format.

Comment: Pandoc is not a true LaTeX converter.  It can only handle a strict subset of LaTeX syntax and concentrates on the mathematics.  See http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-tex for more details.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.